# magento version upgrade 2.4.6-p3 giving Ims error

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.6

After upgrading Magento from version 2.4.3 to 2.4.6-p3 and running a composer update, I encounter an error when executing commands such as bin/magento `setup:di:compile` or bin/magento `setup:upgrade`. Upon inspecting the `composer.lock` file, I noticed that the IMS module is present, despite the release notes indicating its removal from Magento 2.4.6. Attempting to remove this module via composer remove reveals dependencies on other modules, complicating its removal.

[image]